# How to get Twilio worker for incoming calls using TaskRouter? - Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, twilio, twilio-taskrouter

I'm building a simple **Django** contact center app using **Twilio**, **TaskRouter**, **Client JS SDK**.

I'm using the **status_callback** to save the calls log for each customer in db by listening to the request with **complete** **status_callback_event**. (not sure this is the best way but it does the job)

How would you go about saving the worker who received the incoming call?

For outgoing calls I'm passing the request.user in the url as a custom parameter and I'm getting it in the **status_callback**.

For incoming calls I'm getting the **ParentCallSid** in the **status_callback**, I assume I can use it to fetch the client who handled the call through the Rest API.

Am I doing the right thing here? is there a simpler way to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used in the end **TaskRouterEvents** to listen to reservations events (**reservation.completed** or **reservation.canceled**) I took the **WorkerSid** from the POST request and saved it in db. 
I think this is the easiest way to go about doing this. 
For **outgoing** calls I'm passing the **WorkerSid** in the url as a custom parameter and I'm getting it in the status_callback.